# Check if all radio buttons are clicked in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, nginx

For exercise, I've created a small HTML-CSS-JavaScript quiz. The quiz itself works but when I tried to edit a way to check if all radio buttons of the quiz are working (and if not, alert a message to the user), it became broken.

Here is the quiz, with the funcion that checks if the radio buttons are clicked:

```js
let result = 0;

function right() {
  result += 50;
}

function wrong() {
  result -= 50;
}

function obcpq() {
  if (document.querySelector('#quiz:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length) {
    return alert("At least one group is blank");
  } else {
    function showScore() {
      totalScore = result;
      alert(totalScore);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <label>Q1 - X?</label>
  <input type="radio" onclick="right()">Yes
  <input type="radio" onclick="wrong()">No
  <br>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" onclick="wrong()">Yes
  <input type="radio" onclick="right()">No
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="obcpq()" />
  <!-- One Button Chcked Per Question -->
</form>
```

I tried this code after reading of it in this [QA session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920606/jquery-how-to-check-if-all-radio-buttons-in-a-div-are-selected). I also found [this session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899411/jquery-check-to-see-if-all-radiobutton-groups-are-selected) which deals with jQuery and I don't run jQuery on this HTML page.

Why isn't the condition working in my vanilla JavaScript version?

Comment: any error in console? where is the script write? internal or js? is this script attached to on load? is this the error that you hit? `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#quiz:not(:has(:radio:checked))' is not a valid selector."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your HTML code, there's one proportion that can be useful to solve your problem: you want the same number of checked inputs as the number of labels that describe the boxes. When the numbers don't match it's the indicator that not all questions were answered:

```js
let result = 0;

function right() {
  result += 50;
}

function wrong() {
  result -= 50;
}

function obcpq() {
  const labelCount = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz label').length;
  const checkedInputsCount = document.querySelectorAll("#quiz :checked").length;
  if (labelCount !== checkedInputsCount) {
    return alert("At least one group is blank");
  } else {
    function showScore() {
      totalScore = result;
      alert(totalScore);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <label>Q1 - X?</label>
  <input type="radio" onclick="right()">Yes
  <input type="radio" onclick="wrong()">No
  <br>
  <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
  <input type="radio" onclick="wrong()">Yes
  <input type="radio" onclick="right()">No
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="obcpq()" />
  <!-- One Button Chcked Per Question -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add every question in a separate `div` then loop through them and check if the group has at least one checked option `radio`, then use a flag to store the loop result and finally show the right message, like :

```js
let result = 0;

function right() {
  result += 50;
}

function wrong() {
  result -= 50;
}

function obcpq() {
  var groups = document.querySelectorAll('#quiz div');
  var all_checked = true;
  
  for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    if (groups[i].querySelectorAll(':checked').length==0) {
      all_checked = false;
    }
  }
  
  if (!all_checked) {
    console.log('Check please all the radios');
  } else {
    console.log('showScore');
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  <div>
    <label>Q1 - X?</label>
    <input type="radio" onclick="right()">Yes
    <input type="radio" onclick="wrong()">No
  </div>
  <div> <label>Q2 - Y?</label>
    <input type="radio" onclick="wrong()">Yes
    <input type="radio" onclick="right()">No
  </div>
  <input type="button" onclick="obcpq()" value="CHECK"/>
  <!-- One Button Chcked Per Question -->
</form>
```